# Icons of BottomTabBar Navigation are not displayed with a nested StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

I am not able to display tabBarIcon when there is StackNavigator on the same screen.

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Search: {screen: Search},
  About: {screen: About}
  },
  {
      tabBarOptions : {
      showLabel :true,
      showIcon : true,
      style : {
        backgroundColor : "rgb(145, 242, 191)",
        borderTopWidth : 2
    },
    indicatorStyle :{
      height : 10,
      backgroundColor : "#FFF"
    }
  }
});
```

The About screen just renders a basic View, but the Search screen has a StackNavigator that renders both the Search and the List.

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Search : {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions
  },
  List : {
    screen : List,
    navigationOptions
  }
});
```

Everything is working as expected for the About screen but the icons disappeared for the Search screen.

This is for the About :

```
static navigationOptions={
    title:"About",
    tabBarIcon:()=>{
      return (
        <Image source={require("./img/about.png")} style={style.icons}/>
      )
    },
    tabBarLabel : 'About'
  }
```

And this is for Search and List :

```
    title : "Search a city",
    tabBarIcon:()=>{
      return (
        <Image source={require("./img/user.png")} style={style.icons}/>
      )
    },
    headerBackTitle:null,
    tabBarLabel : 'Weather'
  }
```

I have tried to change the title of the screen, it works. But for the Search component, both the Label and the Icon are not working as expected.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks everyone !